# Where to enter Google Maps API key in form.io app

Tags: google-maps, maps

I'm working on my first Form.io app, and according to demos I've seen in various demos, when you use an address field, a Google map will be displayed for that address when the form is viewed. According to [the documentation](https://help.form.io/tutorials/walkthroughs/#customer-resource), I need to add the following code to the header in index.html:

```
 <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

However, I get this error in my console:

```
Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
```

Is there a place in the form.io app where I can/need to enter the API key values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API key can be entered in the src/index.html file found in the main repository. You can see it at

https://github.com/formio/formio-app-servicetracker/blob/master/src/index.html

Replace

`<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>`

with

`<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>`

You can find more information on obtaining a google maps key at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Answer (score 0):

Are you appending the maps script by hand on your website, or using a plugin? Can you send here your website URL? Anyway, here it is how to append the API key: Let's assume that you have the following piece of code

```
<script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To append the apy key, you must add ?key=YOUR_API_KEY at the end of the src path, like this:

```
<script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If, instead, your src path already has some appended parameters (for example, "`//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false`"), just add `&key=YOUR_API_KEY` at the very end: "`//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY`" This is how you append the API parameter (obviously, replace YOUR_API_KEY with your API key code).

More information about  google maps key at

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Your API key should be up and running within 5 minutes. Enjoy!